# Would a question on designing a compression algorithm belong on CS?

Tags: discussion, migration, specific-question

Some time ago, I asked [Compression of domain names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801753/compression-of-domain-names) on StackOverflow.  I had been wondering whether it wouldn't be more suited to CSTheory, but [now understand](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1566/would-a-question-on-designing-a-compression-algorithm-belong-on-cstheory) that it does not.

Is it more suited to CS than SO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, sure, questions on designing algorithms are on-topic here.

Feel free to flag your question on SO to have it migrated here. We would remove the paragraph about existing tools, and your question is a very general one about a very specific problem so you're likely to get bibliographic references for related problems rather than a complete solution, but the question would be basically ok if it was posted here.

Comment: Thanks Gilles.  You'll see from [the question I posted on meta.cstheory](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1566/would-a-question-on-designing-a-compression-algorithm-belong-on-cstheory) that the SO mods would prefer if the migration request was initiated by you guys--is that ok?

Comment: @eggyal You don't need to request a moderator approval on the target site for every migration. Flag, and include a link to my answer here in your flag.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  FYI, the question has now been migrated.